# В IntelliJ IDEA при работе с проектом на Scala, возникли проблемы

Tags: intellij-idea, scala, sbt

Мне нужно написать проект на Scala по данному видео- ролику https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_xX0WjkckTs&t=249s . Проблемы возникли еще в самом начале когда автор ролика открыл файл - build.sbt . Дело в том что у меня не выполняются данные строки из файла(даже стандартные) не говоря уже о внедрении - Akka HTTP, в свой проект . Поскольку я не опытный разработчик , это загнало меня в тупик. Может кто знает в чем может быть проблема?

Ссылка на скрин проблемы:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aSw48Mh31wL16VOUFbSqn76ZhTsXNdf_/view?usp=sharing﻿

Comment: Что значит "не выполняются строки(даже стандартные)"? Что вы ожидаете от их "выполнения"?

Comment: Справа выводит ошибку sbt file must contain only expression

Comment: Кнопка Refresh project не помогает?

Comment: Не помогает,  я менял версию sbt,  чистил кэш,  повторно импортировал проект, перезагрузил программу, обновлял идею .  Ничего из перечисленного не помогает

Comment: Как вариант попробуйте не использовать встроенный в идею `sbt`.

Answer (score 0):

**UPD**: Проблема оказалась в пропущенной запятой в файле `build.sbt`.

**Disclaimer**: Тут скорее косвенное решение проблемы, чем прямое, но мне это в свое время помогло.

---

По-началу тоже бывало сталкивался со странными проблемами встроенного в IDEA `sbt`. Решением многих из них является установка "отдельного" `sbt`. Вот примерно что нужно сделать:

1. [Качаем](https://www.scala-sbt.org/) и устанавливаем `sbt`.
2. В консоли набираем `set PATH`, убеждаемся что есть путь до папки `bin` внутри папки `sbt`. Если нет, то добавляем его.
3. Заходим в корень своего проекта(Я использую вкладку `Terminal` прям в идее) и набираем `sbt`. Теперь доступны все команды сбт, такие как `run`, `compile`, `clear` и `reload`. Последняя нужна перед компиляцией или запуском, если менялся файл `build.sbt`.
4. Если не хочется работать с `sbt` из консоли, а хочется через идею, то идем в `Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> sbt`, и указываем путь до `sbt-launch.jar`, который лежит в папке `bin`:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
5. Кажется, тут надо перезапустить `sbt`, или, как вариант, всю идею целиком(Не уверен насчет необходимости этого шага).
6. Но все-таки ИМХО удобнее через консоль. Рекомендую сразу привыкать к консоли.

Comment: Сделал все через настройки , ниже скрин

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Bkyiekamw0IX44wUJQqsI82emR7M3K3E/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Может я что-то , не правильно сделал по данным указаниям , все равно не работает (

Comment: Та же проблема?

Comment: Выложите код build.sbt на какой-нибудь [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/). Прям копипастом

Comment: Еще появилась вот - такая ошибка : Expression type Def.Setting[Seq[ModuleID]] must conform to DslEntry in sbt fil

Comment: https://pastebin.com/vQfTyh9c

Comment: В строке №10 отсутствует запятая

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WaZ6ElMREFxr_rwsMXdJQHULgXJdOZIM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Так , должно быть ? Сколько возни и все из-за не внимательности. Просто я до этого программировал только на Java

Comment: Не должно. В правой части вертикальные табы. Нажмите таб `sbt` и там иконка refresh в виде стрелочек

Comment: Спасибо, за то что помогли мне , сам бы не разобрался ! )

Comment: Пожалуйста. С сбт у многих и многих проблемы случаются.